# How can I run function from another controller so scope is updated in angular?

Tags: angularjs

In the example below, how can I run getData from another controller and have the scope variable in the view updated?

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.factory('MyService', ['$http',function($http) {
    return {
       getData: function() {
          return $http.get('/api/endpoint');
       }
    };
}]);

app.controller('MyController', ['$scope', '$http', 'MyService', function($scope, $http, MyService){
   MyService.getData().then(function(response){
     $scope.myVarialbe = response.data;
   });
}]);


app.controller('MyController2', ['$scope', '$http', 'MyService', function($scope, $http, MyService){
  ///// ?????? How to get $scope.myVarialbe updated from the getData call?
   });
}]);
```

Comment: You can create on shareable service/factory, which will share a data throughout the app , you can refer [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21919962/share-data-between-angularjs-controllers)

Comment: you can use $rootScope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `$broadcast` and `$on` :

> **$broadcast** dispatches an event name downwards to all child scopes (and their children) and notify to the registered $Scope listeners. The event life cycle starts at the scope on which $broadcast was called. All listeners for the event on this scope get notified.
>
> **$on** listen on events of a given type. It can catch the event dispatched by $broadcast

```
app.controller('MyController', ['$scope', '$http', 'MyService', function($scope, $http, MyService){
   $scope.$on('variableChanged',function(event, value) { 
      $scope.myVariable = value;
   };
}]);


app.controller('MyController2', ['$scope', '$http', 'MyService', function($scope, $http, MyService){
  MyService.getData().then(function(response){
     $scope.$broadcast('variableChanged', response.data);
  });
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
angular.module('app').controller('nav', function($scope,$http) {
 $rootScope.$on("CallMethodNavController", function(){
   $scope.navMethod();
}); 
$scope.navMethod=function(){
$http.get('/players').then(function(data) {
$scope.numOfPlayers = data.players.length;
}    
});
});
```

then in the second controller you call this method once a player is added like so:

```
    $rootScope.$emit("CallMethodNavController", {});
```